# Executing threads taking turns

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a function that just prints thread id it is called from. I want 2 threads call this function **taking turns** n times. I had implemented this functionality in pthreads with a  condition variable but it is too verbose. What I want program to print as follows:

```
id: 0
id: 1
id: 0
id: 1
id: 0
id: 1
...
```

In the end, "id: 0" and "id: 1" should be printed n times.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this OpenMP?

Comment: An interesting thought problem, but it needs to be noted that sequencing the threads like this is a pointless use of threads. Sounds like your trick with the condition variables is a good one. Perhaps you should show it to us so we can find ways to simplify it for you. It's also possible that what you see as "too verbose" is as good as it gets.

Comment: Actually the question isn't really clear to me, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be good

Comment: While this makes for a very interesting puzzle, it does smell like a X/Y problem. Alternating threads sounds like the way you chose to tackle some synchronization challenge we are no privy to, but there might be a better way to tackle that underlying objective. Would it be possible to share a bit more context?

Comment: I am currently constructing a benchmark that measures the latency when a variable is modified from 2 different threads, each taking turns, n times in total. In each run of the benchmark, threads are bound to different core pairs and I am comparing the latencies of all runs.

Comment: @AydinÖzcan Thank you for that. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, my gut would be that synchronization mechanisms would easily dominate the benchmark, and this might be one of the few cases where a furious spinlock would give more accurate results. Maybe something like https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3Pjhhd3e8

Comment: Your suggestion on spinlock is on point. I was using std::lock_guard with std::mutex (and std::condition_variable ofc) and I think spinlock would better fit for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the thread number against your iteration count and implement the handoff with a barrier.

```
#include <omp.h>

#include <cstdio>


int main()
{
  /* note that it is not pragma omp parallel for, just a parallel block */
# pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if((i & 1) == (omp_get_thread_num() & 1))
      std::printf("%d: thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
#   pragma omp barrier
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not super-versed in OpenMP, so I may be way off-base, but: My understanding of `barrier` is that all it does is make both threads wait for each other when they reach that point, but that doesn't prevent them from running concurrently, which is what the OP wants. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Frank Because there is a check against the thread number, one thread is always directly going to the barrier

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP has mentioned that this is for benchmarking cross-core latency, a purely `std::atomic`-based solution should probably be at least considered.

Using C++20's `wait()`, we can do the following:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic<int> target(1);

void worker(int wid, int n) {
  int v = wid;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {    
    target.wait(v);       // wait until target has a different value than v

    // Do stuff...    
    // std::cout << wid;

    v = target.load() + 1;
    target.store(v);      // increment target
    target.notify_one();  // Wakeup the other thread.
  }
}

int main() {
  int n = 100;

  std::jthread t0(worker, 0, n);
  std::jthread t1(worker, 1, n);
}
```

Admittedly, this is a bit by-the-seat-of-your-pants during bootstrapping.
Here's what's going on:

- `t0`'s first `wait()` will immediately pass, since `0 != 1`, and nothing can change `target` beforehand.
- `t1`'s first `wait()`, won't proceed until `t0` moves `target` away from its initial value: 1.
- If `t0` performs its `notify_one()` before `t1` reaches its `wait()`, then `t1`'s wait won't block since `target` is already 2 by then.
- After that, both thread always `wait()` for the value to change from the one they have set, which will cause them to alternate.

Obviously, this only works for 2 threads.

Comment: How would performance change if I chose to implement benchmark with spinlock instead of std::atomic constructs? Do you have any guess here?

Comment: @AydinÖzcan A spinlock would still need to use atomic constructs (albeit slightly different ones). How much of a performance different it makes will depend a lot. Typically, spinlocks waste CPU to get lower latency, so you can get **potentially** faster cross-thread reaction time, but lower program-wide performance. How that compares to `std::atomic::wait()` is highly implementation dependant. Implementors may very well choose to do a spinlock that decay into an OS-lock after a small timeout. (That's certainly how I would do it)

Comment: I will try pthread_spinlock(3) to observe the difference. Btw, this is kind of off-topic but, is it important to mark function I call in my benchmark "inline" to avoid all possible jitters? I am aiming to discard all possible jitters possible and spin lock is surely a step in the right direction and I am looking for me. Also can we use std::atomic_wait() in this context and what difference would it make, do you have experience with it? I may also consider seqlock. Thanks!

Comment: @AydinÖzcan To eliminate jitter you must: a) Use a real-time operating system b) Not use any system calls, This generally precludes using most OS-provided locks. Writing your own spinlock using `std::atomic` is easy though.